# Chromedriver vs. Chrome update incompatibility

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I was working on setting up RSelenium in R to interact with Chrome; however, I keep receiving an error message that the Chrome driver can't work with my version of Chrome even though I already specified the version of the Chromedriver to match Chrome on my desktop.

Below is the code producing an error: (MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.5)

```
library(RSelenium)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(wdman)
library(binman)
```

```
remDr <- RSelenium::remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                                port = 4445L,
                                browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
```

```
binman::list_versions("chromedriver")

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever="75.0.3770.90")
```

list versions from binman are:"75.0.3770.90" "76.0.3809.12" "76.0.3809.25"

The error that I kept receiving is as follows:
Selenium message:session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76
  (Driver info: chromedriver=76.0.3809.25 (a0c95f440512e06df1c9c206f2d79cc20be18bb1-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#271}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.5 x86_64)

However, I checked the version that Chrome is updated to and it is 75.0.3770.100 so I assumed that the chrome driver that I specified would be suffice.

I tried a couple different methods such as adding the following functions; however, I keep receiving the same error.

```
eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(
args = c('--no-sandbox','--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1280,800')
))
cDrv <- chrome()
```

I was wondering if there was anyway to remove the higher versions of chrome driver so there is only one chrome driver the code to possibly use. Any other solutions would also be very much appreciated!

Comment: **Not relevant to the question** but calling `library(tidyverse)` means you don't need to call `library(dplyr);library(purrr)` independently.

Comment: The error message says "ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 76" but you say you are running Chrome version "75.0.3770.100". Those don't match. you should [download](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) the ChromeDriver for version 75 (not 76).

Comment: Maybe try adding `verbose=TRUE` to `rsDriver`. It's unclear why it's trying to use the latest version of the driver when you've specified the older version.

Comment: I already downloaded the ChromeDriver version 75 which is why it appears when I call ```binman::list_versions("chromedriver")```. But I have ChromeDriver 76 and 75 downloaded so I wonder if its not reading the other options? I tried ```verbose = TRUE ``` but it still has the same error

Comment: But did the verbose output contain any additional information about what was going on? Can you uninstall the versions of the driver that use the beta version of Chrome? That way they can't accidentally be used. Or maybe try `check=FALSE` in the `rsDriver` call.

Comment: It was the exact same error. However, I was able to solve the problem by just giving up and taking a risk by downloading the beta version of Google chrome.